# SSH double hop with port forward and remote command that returns immediately

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a remote host behind a bastion that I need to setup port forwards to, I have come up with the following:

```
bastion=xyz.com
user=$( whoami )

function doSSH () {

    ssh $user@$bastion -t -A \
        -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 \
        ssh $user@$1 -t -A \
            -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 \
            '/opt/enableVNC && while [ 1 ]; do echo "Keeping forwards alive..." && sleep 60; done'
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that after SSHing to the remote node, I must run a script that enabled the VNC server on the node, unfortunately, this script shortly returns `0` once the server is up and running. The script I am calling is not a blocking script, and the ssh session comes to a close, even though I have established the port forwards.

```
$ doSSH node1
user@xyz.com's password:
user@node1's password:
  VNC is now Enabled
  Listening on 127.0.0.1:5900
Connection to node1 closed.
Keeping forwards alive...
Keeping forwards alive...
```

It seems as if the connection to the second host is broken immediately after the first part of the command returns, and I can not keep the connection open to the second host.

How can I keep my port forward established after making a call that immediately returns?

Comment: Did you try that with `ProxyCommand` and IO forwarding with `-W`? It is much less messy and much more secure, if it is allowed by the bastion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used the quotes when running the command (otherwise, the while loop executes locally). Are you able to create a script on the remote host? If so, you could create a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/opt/enableVNC && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; done
```

And run the script in your `ssh` session.

Comment: Yes, I am running the command in quotes. The loop currently seems to run on the bastion, after the session from the node exists on the return of the script. I was hoping to have this as a single dynamic script run by the end user, and not have to modify the already widely distributed linux image.

Comment: Tried that, they did not..

Answer (score 0):

How about this ugly piece of code:

```
bastion=xyz.com
user=$( whoami )

function doSSH () {

    ssh $user@$bastion -t -A \
        -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 \
        'bash -c "ssh '$user'@'$1' -t -A \
            -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 \
            bash -c \"/opt/enableVNC  && while [ 1 ]; do echo Keeping forwards alive... && sleep 60; done\""'
}
```